# TypeScript Generic & Function Overloading

Tags: typescript

I want to write such a factory function (which returns a function), it accepts 1-2 generic types (`R` and `P`, `P` is optional):

- if it gets 1 generic type, then it returns a function in shape of `() => R`.
- if it gets 2, then it returns a function in shape of `(p: P) => R`.

```js
type MapLike = Record<string, any>;

function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike>(
  key: string,
): () => R;

function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike, P extends MapLike>(
  key: string,
): (param: P) => R;
```

How can I do it? I feel that it's a problem of function overloading.

I try the following way, it works when it accepts 2 types, but failed with 1 type only.

```js
type MapLike = Record<string, any>;

function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike, P extends MapLike = never>(
  key: string,
) {
  return function (p: P): R {
    return doSomeThing(key, p);
  }
};
```

- with 2 types, it works

  ```js
  type Pe = { foo: string };
  type Re = { bar: string };
  const myFn = createSomeFn<Re, Pe>('myFn');

  // ✅ It alerts me that there should be a `p` argument
  // myFn();
  // ^^^^^^ error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

  myFn({ foo: 'bar' });
  ```
- with 1 type, it fails

  ```js
  type Re = { bar: string };
  const myFn = createSomeFn<Re>('myFn');

  // ❌ It should let me go, but raise error
  // myFn();
  // ^^^^^^ error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

  // myFn({});
  // ^^^^^^^^ error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
  ```

Comment: You can either overload it, or use a generic conditional type, both of which are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/weaadw).  Do either of those meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I read your solution and I think it meets my needs! I have tried to write some "extends" expression like what your do in namespace `Single`, but finally I gave up T_T~ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a single function you'd like to be able to call in distinct ways, you can either [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) it, or possibly make it [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to represent arbitrary type relationships.

---

For your example, the overload solution is relatively straightforward: just add a call signature for each desired way to call it:

```
// call signatures
function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike>(key: string): () => R;
function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike, P extends MapLike>(
  key: string): (param: P) => R;
```

and then implement it with a signature that would allow any such call (at least):

```
function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike, P extends MapLike = never>(
  key: string) {
  return function (p: P): R {
    return null! // impl later
  }
};
```

---

If you want to use generic conditional types instead, you need to determine what the return type will be as a function of the input types.  You want to compare `P` to `never`, and return `() => R` if it matches, and `(p: P) => R` if it doesn't match.  Here's one way to do that:

```
function createSomeFn<R extends MapLike, P extends MapLike = never>(
  key: string,
) {
  return function (...[p]: ([P] extends [never] ? [] : [p: P])): R {
    return null! // impl later
  }
};
```

The check is of the form `[P] extends [never] ? ⋯ : ⋯` and not `P extends never ? ⋯ : ⋯` because we don't want a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) (see [microsoft/TypeScript#23182](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23182)).  And here I'm choosing which [rest parameter tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) of use depending on `P`.  If `P` is `never`, then the parameters list should be empty (`[]`), otherwise it should be a one-tuple of type `P` (`[p: P]`).

---

Both solutions behave the way you want:

```
type Pe = { foo: string };
type Re = { bar: string };
const myFn = createSomeFn<Re, Pe>('myFn');
myFn(); // error
myFn({ foo: 'bar' }); // okay
const myFn2 = createSomeFn<Re>('myFn');
myFn2(); // okay
myFn2({}); // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=9#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkgC4CeMyAsiDADICWA1sgLxIBKE8A9gE4AmAHijFe9YAHMANEhDBSAPgDc+QklCRYCZAHkAbhF4ZuIfnlVEiAMwCuweMXrdgSeLwghiEAMrdIAMWBBdiQIAA8vYH4oJGo6JggFAAo1SyRmUgAuJBExSSlUpABKbKSipBYFDhVC23tHZ1d3Tx8-CEDg0IiIKJi4hmYZAAUuyOjYmgHElLSiDOzc8WlCkqQkuF5wbKHyyuqLSzqHJxc3Dy9fAKCQ8LG+yYTh0Z7x-oSK9QgDXmTCuYgsjlREsCmlygRZkh3MQbLwXEcGi51ttViEIZCoRAYXD1DYMBgAIRIAD0xKQ9DAMAwSAwLV4fyQAF9CoyamkyBQkENWHgkFZuNwFsDJEyVOzyMhOB9cEgAEYgXhCvISUWFHjAERIMCkQIfM4tS7ta4QYbTADk2sCZqKbMsluAZTFdp1Dpl-MFSDN8t4ZqZNoORHVmvtACY9c0Lm0OpxkhaXdbbURQ47CsncIz-URmWoNNA4IgkN4lhhkOjrHZjo19ZGrp1bi97vFBlznr0Jk2ecAvoZfpD5kDlaDLOCGdDYfCK4i1gA6WcAbRgAF1SnOhovW+M513vuuAPxIOfr7IL7aLoqo8wYzHYlzAPGEklkilUml0hnMtKsgMkCVcnlugUlSWVVxU5KU2Blb0gJFL80iDYgtRdcNzlaWtOFNWN7QTVMXUdR9Ql4Xg+BwwIkgAj0vQVX0MyUfDuEYEBSDVZxgxdMM2GrVCjWCc0sMzZ1AhDPDSSQejGJI4AhPTG18MMIj6TUbNGSAA)